# Como fazer um select dentro de outro select no mysql

Tags: mysql, select, where

Preciso pegar o menor valor de uma coluna para usá-la como condição no `where`, mas não sei como fazer isso. A coluna que preciso é a `ordering`, como abaixo:

```
SELECT p.pro_name, p.id, f.image as foto
FROM #__osrs_properties p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT image, pro_id
    FROM #__osrs_photos
    WHERE ordering = "menor ordering"
) f ON f.pro_id = p.id
ORDER BY pro_name DESC
LIMIT 21
```

As tabelas estão assim:

```
osrs_properties

id|pro_name
1 | joao
2 | nome
3 | maria

osrs_photos

id|pro_id|    image    | ordering
1 | 1    | imagem1.jpg | 2
2 | 1    | imagem2.jpg | 1
3 | 2    | imagem3.jpg | 1
```

Comment: Não consegui compreender o que você precisa. Pode explicar melhor?

Comment: O que você espera que esse `select` retorna?

Comment: eu preciso que ele traga qual o menor ordering, por exemplo (SELECT MIN(ordergin) FROM #__osrs_photos) aí vou usar essa informação onde está o WHERE ordering = "menor ordering"

Comment: não sei ao certo se é um select dentro de outro, ou teria uma outra forma

Comment: Ok, mas você tem dois `ordering` menores, edita a pergunta e coloca uma tabela com o retorno que você precisa

Comment: Um `ORDER BY ordering LIMIT 1` não resolve?

Comment: Respondi a sua pergunta, da uma olhada se é isso que você precisa. caso não for, tenta colocar um exemplo de como você gostaria que os registros aparecessem na tela, pra gente entender melhor e poder te ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Será que assim resolve o que você precisa?

```
SELECT p.pro_name, p.id, f.image as foto, Max(f.ordering) AS orderingmax
FROM osrs_properties p
LEFT JOIN osrs_photos as f ON f.pro_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.pro_name, p.id
ORDER BY p.pro_name, orderingmax DESC
LIMIT 21
```

Você usa o Max(f.ordering) para buscar os itens de maior valor.
O Left Join para fazer uma integração da tabela de imagem com a tabela de proprietarios
E o group para agrupar os valores que repetem como nome e id do proprietario para não exibir registros duplicados.

Testa ai e me avisa se deu certo.

Abraços

Comment: Acho que só confundi o esquema de ordem que você precisa. Você pode mudar o Max por Min, caso seja a ordem inversa.

Comment: exatamente isso, deu certo, só com o que vc comentou, é min e não max...rs, valew!!!

Comment: Que bom que consegui ajudar. tmj brother ^^ abraços

Answer (score 1):

Seria isso?

```
SELECT 
    p.pro_name, 
    p.id, 
    f.image as foto
FROM 
    osrs_properties p
LEFT JOIN 
    osrs_photos f ON f.pro_id = p.id
AND f.pro_id in (
    SELECT MIN(pro_id) FROM osrs_photos ORDER BY ordering LIMIT 1
    );
```

Comment: deu esse erro:  #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo Fiz uma alteração na Query, verifique se funciona, por favor

Comment: Precisa mesmo da sub-sql? Por que não ordena por `ordering` a consulta principal e limita o resultado em 1?